# If statement invalid syntax error

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

I cannot figure out where the error is coming from because as far as i can see the code is correct and has no obvious errors in it.

code:

```
if grid_list[grid_list.index(ant_position)][0] == 1 or grid_list[grid_list.index(ant_position)][1] == 1:
    print("boom")
    if grid_list[grid_list.index(ant_position)][1] ==1 and grid_list[grid_list.index(ant_position)][0] == 1:
        print("1,1")
    else:
        if grid_list[grid_list.index(ant_position)][1] == grid_size or grid_list[grid_list.index(ant_position)][0] == grid_size:
            if grid_list[grid_list.index(ant_position)][0] == grid_size:
                print("gridsize,1")
            else:
                print("1,gridsize")
        else:
            if grid_list[grid_list.index(ant_position)][0] == 1:
                print("1,something")
            else:
                print("something,1")
else:
    if grid_list[grid_list.index(ant_position)[0] == grid_size or grid_list[grid_list.index(ant_position)][1] == grid_size:
        print("boom")
        if grid_list[grid_list.index(ant_position)][1] == grid_size and grid_list[grid_list.index(ant_position)][0] == grid_size:
            print("gridsize,gridsize")
        else:
            if grid_list[grid_list.index(ant_position)][0] == grid_size:
                print("gridsize,something")
            else:
                print("something,gridsize")
    else:       
    print("boo")
```

The error is supposedly occuring on the line just above the print("gridsize,gridsize") on the colon at the end of the if statement. I have no idea what the problem is. any helps appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it is because of this line

```
if grid_list[grid_list.index(ant_position)[0] == grid_size or grid_list[grid_list.index(ant_position)][1] == grid_size:
```

you are missing a closing square bracket in `grid_list[grid_list.index(ant_position)[0]`

It should have been `grid_list[grid_list.index(ant_position)][0]`, I believe.

**Edit** As Peter suggested in the comments, store the result of `grid_list.index(ant_position)` in a variable and use the variable wherever needed.

Comment: For the sake of readability and performance, stop calling `grid_list.index(ant_position)` everywhere. Call it once and keep the value.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Thats true. I ll add your suggestion in the answer.

Comment: I suspect there are other ways this code could be cleaned up, but that's an easy one. Actually, now this hurts my head - the OP constantly looks up `grid_list[grid_list.index(ant_position)]`. But isn't that just a slow and cumbersome way to get `ant_position`? Assuming `grid_list` is a normal sequence type and not something with a custom `index`, anyway.

Comment: yeah I spotted it about 1 minute after i posted the question :3 i was looking in the wrong place because of where the syntax error was highlighting :L thankyou very much though and yeah that is a good idea but it would require constant iterations of a function ive written so i probabaly wont bother :L

Comment: ahhhh thank you very much for pointing out the grid_list thing :L that really shortens down my code :)